# Bootstrap popup doesn't appear when click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div id="freewall" class="freewall">
    <g:each in="${list}" var="image">
        <div class="brick">
            <div class="grid-tile">
                <a class="overlay" href="/more/${image.id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailModal">
                <img src="${image.referralImage}" width="100%" />
                </a>

            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <p class="title">${image.tags}</p>
                <p class="owner">by ${image.description}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </g:each>
</div>


<div id="detailModal" class="modal hide mod pure-g t-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>

</div>
```

Using bootstrap with dynamic images and its details.

At first, I used

```
$('#detailModal').modal('show');
```

The issue is that when page is loading, the detailModal will appear when it shouldn't.

```
$('#detailModal').modal('hide');
  $('.grid-tile a').on('click', function(){
  $('#detailModal').modal('show');
});
```

When page is loading, the detailModal doesn't appear. BUT when I click on grid-tile for popup detail on image, it doesn't do anything, meaning no popup at all.

I couldn't figure where I could overlook or go wrong. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you page get refreshed after clicking on link. Try to use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) like,

```
$('.grid-tile a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();// to prevent page refresh
    $('#detailModal').modal('show');
});
```

Hope, it works or five an online demo of your code.

Answer (score 0):

you could try putting a class on the a tag directly and referencing that rather than grid-title a

also try using the click function so

```
$('#detailModal').modal('hide');
$('.newAnchorClassName').click(){
    $('#detailModal').modal('show');
};
```

finally check to see if there are any javascript errors being fired

Comment: I also used .overlay class but it also does not work. there is no js error

Comment: After you click the a tag does the hide class on the modal get removed in the html markup? If it does then does the aria-hidden='true' also go? I think in the past I have needed to remove this manually